# imacros - read text file using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, loops, imacros

I want to read text file using javascript not using imacros loop

I tried to read it using java with no luck

> function frdln(n){   var fr,s='';   try{
>
> ```
> fr=new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(n));
>
> s=fr.readLine();
>
> if(s==null){s=''}else{s=''+s};
>
> fr.close();
>
> fr=null;   }catch(e){
>
> alert(''+e);   };   return s; };
> ```

give me message error "ReferenceError: java is not defined"

> Note:I installed latest version of java and the same error appear

if there is any other way to read text file or fix my code because I have no idea

Comment: See [IMacro Scripting - How to read a local .txt file using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239650/imacro-scripting-how-to-read-a-local-txt-file-using-javascript). Java and JavaScript are two totally different languages. You can't use one inside the other like this.

Comment: @Boann this solution use "XMLHttpRequest" work only in internet explorer and I must use firefox

Comment: ‎@user3162193 I think it should work [in every browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @Boann in firefox give this messsage error ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined,
also  in the answer you can see the Respondent say "You have to use xml http request as Activex object of file is not supported by any other browser than IE."

Comment: ‎@user3162193 [does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194092/http-post-in-imacros-with-javscript-for-firefox)

Comment: @Boann thank you a lot it's work when I added Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using javascript this can work XMLHttpRequest() but XMLHttpRequest() is no longer supported in firefox 15+ You must have to define it:

const XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1");
var request = XMLHttpRequest();

Answer (score 0):

Install FireFox 15 and don't update it and that function will work. Java is not supported in FF16+ but in FF15 it works.