# Extract multiple occurrences in JSON file with iMacros

Tags: regex, json, imacros

I'm using iMacros for Firefox and want to extract some id's from a JSON file. The JSON file looks like this:

```
"count":0,"id":"12345","time"
blabla
"count":0,"id":"12346","time"
```

The code I'm using in iMacros is:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.jsonurl.com
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"\"id\":\"(.[^\"]*)\"" EXTRACT="$1"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

With this code, it is only extracting **12345** from the above JSON example. How can I edit the code to extract all occurrences of id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JavaScript solution.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="URL GOTO=https://www.jsonurl.com"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:what_ever_you_are_extracting EXTRACT=HTM"+"\n";

iimPlay(macro)

var text=iimGetLastExtract();

text=text.split('"id":"')[1];
text=text.split('",')[0];

text=text.trim();

alert(text);
```

Edit:

The command

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM
```

Extracts everything on the page.

Comment: I'm getting the error: ReferenceError: iimGetLastExtact is not defined, line 9 (Error code: -991)?

Comment: var text=iimGetLastExtact(0);

Comment: I edited and made the right code the letter "r" is missing in iimGetLastExtact();

Comment: Thanks, got it working for normal html pages. But this json file doens't have the div and classes structure so I don't know what to fill in for ATTR=CLASS.

Comment: Is it a file on a link somewhere? Or on your hard drive?

Comment: It is a link to a facebook URL. I'm trying to scrape user ID's.

Comment: Download it on hard drive and use this to load that file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953736/imacros-read-text-file-using-javascript/21956427#21956427

Comment: First, this is not possible because the content on the URL is constantly changing. Second: I don't see why this could be a solution? iMacros can read the json file, it just don't have structure like a normal html page with divs, id's and classes.

Comment: Can you give us exactly what you are extracting. This is command that works on all pages. TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM

Comment: Awesome! I used that command and now I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no can do :(

> Global, iterative matching is currently not supported, so only the first match on the page can be found and extracted.

[Source (iMacros Wiki)](http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH)